# How to "rebuild" the CDK entrypoint

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

A bit of background, started a CDK in typescript project and didn't know the conventions as I'm new to AWS so the code was written on the "entrypoint" in the /bin directory. Upon further [reading](https://cdkworkshop.com/20-typescript/20-create-project/300-structure.html) I found out that I was doing it incorrectly

> bin/cdk-workshop.ts is the entrypoint of the CDK application. It will load the stack defined in lib/cdk-workshop-stack.ts.

So my question is, after I move my code from the /bin file to the /lib, how do I then generate the bin/cdk-workshop.ts file again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cdk.json file defines the entry point of the application. In the article you linked note this bullet point:

```
cdk.json tells the toolkit how to run your app. In our case it will be "npx ts-node bin/cdk-workshop.ts"
```

Edits:

> So my question is, after I move my code from the /bin file to the
> /lib, how do I then generate the bin/cdk-workshop.ts file again?

So `cdk init` is just a tool to help developers with scaffolding the starter project. This is the only time the code gets 'generated'. You don't need to generate the file again. You can just edit it. The reason it is the entrypoint is because it creates an instance of `App` and it creates instances of `Stacks`. You can name the file whatever you want.

For example, let's instead create a folder called `entrypoint` at the same level of `bin` and `lib`. In this folder we create a file called `startup.ts`

Here could be the code for `startup.ts`

```
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import { MyCoolStack} from '../lib/my-cool-stack';
import { MyLameStack} from '../lib/my-lame-stack';

const app = new cdk.App();

new MyCoolStack(app, 'MyCoolStack', {});

new MyLameStack(app, 'MyLameStack', {});
```

And then there are 2 options for defining this file as the entrypoint.

- Inline
- cdk.json

Inline
`cdk synth --app "npx ts node entrypoint/startup.ts"`

cdk.json

```
{
  "app":"npx ts node entrypoint/startup.ts"
}
```

Just a note, I have never developed a cdk app in typescript, just C#, so these are my assumptions based on how it works for a C# project.

Comment: Doesn't this rely on the code already being written in `lib/cdk-workshop-stack.ts` which in turn generates the code `bin/cdk-workshop.ts`? At the moment there is no code in `bin/cdk-workshop.ts` as i moved it into `lib/cdk-workshop-stack.ts`

Comment: I edited the original answer to provide a more detailed explanation

Comment: I see, that makes more sense now, thank you!